# Debugging JQuery Mobile on my Android

Tags: css, debugging, mobile

I have an application that I want to debug through my phone. I need to edit some css, (or see why its looking how it is)

Is there anything like Firebug for mobile debugging? Or is there another approach?

To add a bit more detail here is the problem. I have a title bar (`data-role="header"`) with this css:

```
.ui-bar-a 
{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #ffffff, #ffffff) repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: none;
}
```

It works fine on my PC (the background color is white) but its black on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

two things to try:

1. Add that CSS class to an element that's not the title bar, which is probably getting quite manipulated by the JQuery Mobile framework
2. What browser are you using on the PC? Try the page in Chrome as well as Firefox etc.

Comment: The browsers were the problem. When I was running it on my phone I was using chrome, and I debugged it for firefox opera an IE (Idk why I skipped chrome, apparently IE doesn't even have a mobile browser)